# How can I manage the relationship between product options and warehouse items in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, e-commerce

I'm building an e-commerce site.

Take a look at the options on this product at the nordstrom rack website.

https://www.nordstromrack.com/shop/product/890005/pink-owl-pink-owl-heavenly-solid-flare-dress?color=PINK#results

My website will have something similar.

The problem is, 1 product on the website, with 3x3 options, actually translates to 9 different products at the "warehouse".

So I have a database for website products, and a database for warehouse entries.

How do I define the relationship between these two databases, assuming an indefinite amount of variable options?

My solution is to basically have an EAV database that connects the two. It would store single attributes for warehouse items, and would also have ID's that relate it to the website product. It would be queried to identify which warehouse item relates to the selected product options.

It would look something like this:

> product_id,warehouse_id,attr,value

And the warehouse db would look something like this (simplified)

> warehouse_id,product_id,quantity_available

Where the product_id is the product on the website that this item belongs to.

So, if I wanted to find a warehouse item that belongs to product_id : 1337 and has attributes color : green and size : small, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT warehouse_id FROM DATABASE_NAME WHERE product_id=1337 AND 
((attr='color' AND value='green') OR (attr='size' AND value='small'));
```

I would then parse the result set and find 2 entries that have the same warehouse_id. That would be the id that has both color = green and size = small.

However, I think this method sucks. It requires to create a preposterously large database. Where in a 3x3 option case, you need 9 warehouse entries for every product, you would need 2 EAV entries for every warehouse entry, which means 18 total EAV entries for a product.

Do you guys have any better suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I figured out how to simplify my query with inner join. It requires no parsing.

```
select a.warehouse_id from warehouse_EAV a, warehouse_EAV b
where a.product_id=1337 AND a.warehouse_id=b.warehouse_id AND 
(a.attr='color' AND a.val='green') AND (b.attr='size' AND b.val='small');
```

Comment: *"EDIT: I figured out how to simplify my query with inner join. It requires no parsing."* - What was it that I said about a JOIN earlier? I knew I shouldn't have deleted that comment ;-) Hey, am just glad it worked out of you. Cheers

Comment: Haha yeah you were right!

Comment: Right on, glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "preposterously large" database.  There is no magic, you have to store all the pieces of the puzzle really. I might just be missing your question entirely, though.

Seems to me the model sounds something like:

Products has product variations. Warehouses store inventory of product variations.

```
PRODUCTS (product_id, name)
PRODUCT_VARIATIONS (product_var_id, product_id, variation_id, value)
VARIATION_DIMENSION (product_id, variation_id, name)
VARIATION_CHOICES (variation_id, choice_value)
WAREHOUSES (warehouse_id, name, location)
INVENTORY (product_var_id, warehouse_id, quantity, cost, on_order)
```

and if you are going to show the products:

```
select p.product_id, name, min(price) min_price, max(price) max_price
from products p, product_variations pv
where p.product_id = pv.product_id
group by p.product_id, name
```

Example.

You have a Shirt. It comes in S, M, L. It has Red and Blue.

```
PRODUCTS: 
( 'SHIRT1', 'Really cool shirt!' )

PRODUCT_VARIATION: (Key is product_var_id, variation_id)
( 'R_S_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Red' )
( 'R_S_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Small' )
( 'R_M_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Red' )
( 'R_M_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Medium' )
( 'R_L_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Red' )
( 'R_L_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Large' )
( 'B_S_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Blue' )
( 'B_S_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Small' )
( 'B_M_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Blue' )
( 'B_M_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Medium' )
( 'B_L_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Blue' )
( 'B_L_SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Large' )

VARIATION_DIMENSIONS (Key is product_id, variation_id)
('SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Color')
('SHIRT1', 'SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Size')

VARIATION_CHOICES (Key is both variation_id, choice_value)
('SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Red')
('SHIRT1_COLOR', 'Blue')
('SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Small')
('SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Medium')
('SHIRT1_SIZE', 'Large')

WAREHOUSES
('NYC01', 'Main Warehouse', 'New York, NY')

INVENTORY
( 'R_S_SHIRT1', 'NYC01', 5, 3.00, 0 )
( 'R_M_SHIRT1', 'NYC01', 0, 3.00, 10 )
( 'R_L_SHIRT1', 'NYC01', 6, 3.00, 0 )
( 'B_S_SHIRT1', 'NYC01', 1, 3.00, 10 )
( 'B_M_SHIRT1', 'NYC01', 0, 3.00, 10 )
( 'B_L_SHIRT1', 'NYC01', 3, 3.00, 0 )
```

How many red small shirts are in stock?

```
SELECT * 
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE product_var_id IN (
    SELECT product_var_id
    FROM   PRODUCT_VARIATIONS
    WHERE  value = 'Red'
    AND    variation_id = 'SHIRT1_COLOR'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT product_var_id
    FROM   PRODUCT_VARIATIONS
    WHERE  value = 'Small'
    AND    variation_id = 'SHIRT1_SIZE'
)
```

Comment: Product variations have to be indeterminate. "size, color, price" won't do.

Comment: What I mean by preposterously large is, for every 3x3 product, you end up with 18 different entries in the EAV database.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve, is how do I assign indeterminate options to each warehouse item? I can't just add them as columns because I don't know what the options are or how many there are.

Comment: Right but each has to be tracked for inventory purposes anyhow.  Right?  You need to know if there is a green shirt in a small.

Comment: Ok that helps.  And you want it to also be limitless right?  There needs to be support for 100 choosable options on a product, for example, right?

Comment: Correct. But I don't know what options each product will have. The store will carry a variety of products. I need a dynamic way of assigning and parsing options.

Comment: Yes, to the second question

Comment: Ok I updated it with a new concept of variation_dimension and veriation_choices.  So You might have (1, 1, 'colors'), and (1, 1, 1, 'red'), (1, 1, 2, 'blue').  You might also need product_id to make it specific.  You probably want some variation of this method I think.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your idea. Could you give me an example of how I would use your structure to find a warehouse item given a product_id and a couple of options?

Comment: Something like that.  There aren't simple ways of accomplishing limitless conditions like this.

Comment: That would work, but the total amount of rows is actually higher than my solution. I think I'll just implement my solution, but I figured out how I can use a SELF JOIN to simplify my query.